# OnClientClick fired before ValidationGroup

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validationgroup

This is the code i'm using:

```
            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtTitre" runat="server" Skin="Windows7" Width="250">
            </telerik:RadTextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
                ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="txtTitre" ValidationGroup="validationincident"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

And my ASP button:

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Soumettre ce ticket" OnClick="Button1_Click"
            OnClientClick="CloseDialog()" UseSubmitBehavior="false" ValidationGroup="validationincident" />
```

My problem is it seems OnClientClick is fired before ValidationGroup since the JS function called in my OnClientClick Closes my window.

So the window closes and the "*" (error message) is only displayed when i reopen my window.

I need my ValidationGroup to be checked first!
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `Page_ClientValidate()` which checks the client validations

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Soumettre ce ticket" OnClick="Button1_Click"
            OnClientClick="if(Page_ClientValidate()) CloseDialog();" UseSubmitBehavior="false" ValidationGroup="validationincident" />
```

Comment: i used this and wonder why the messagebox appears twice? i usesd a validation summary and set is show message box to true, any fix? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `Page_ClientValidate()` which checks the client validations

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
     OnClientClick="if(Page_ClientValidate()) CloseDialog();" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
```

In addition, you can also specify the validation group **`Page_ClientValidate(validationGroup)`**, in case you have multiple validations on your page:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="myGroup"
      OnClientClick="if(Page_ClientValidate('myGroup')) CloseDialog();" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Make causesValidation="true" for button.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same Problem. This is how i solved it.

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="myGroup" OnClientClick="Page_ClientValidate()){ return CloseDialog();}else { return false;}" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```